# how to read and store multiple images from url in internal storage

Tags: android, image, internal-storage

i am trying to insect and read different images from a url ..
 . String name array completes the urls. and save the images in intenal storage .
this is how i am insecting it

```
String[] name={"dove.jpg","man.jpg","rat.jpg"}; 
String fileName="code";
    try {
                                URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2/picure/"+name");
                                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                                conn.setDoInput(true);
                                conn.connect();
                                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                                FileOutputStream fos = getActivity().openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                                ByteArrayOutputStream outstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outstream);
                                byte[] byteArray = outstream.toByteArray();

                                fos.write(byteArray);
                                fos.close();
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity()," connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } catch(Exception e) {



            }
```

this is how i want to read it

```
category_logo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_category_logo);
String path = mContext.getFilesDir().toString();
        String fileName = "code";

        if (fileName != null && !fileName.equals("")) {
            Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path + "/" + fileName);
            if (bMap != null) {
                 category_logo.setImageBitmap(bMap);
            }
        }
```

but with the way i stored this it is meant to have three images .. how to view like the second or third one since they have the file name.

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Comment: how to store images not read from url

Comment: Storing images in Database is not a good idea. However you can save them on the SD - somewhere where the user can't delete them or you will end up having a date with NullPointer Exception.

Comment: you have to give them different file names. otherwise, you are simply overwriting the same file over and over again. a good example of file name in your case would be the name of the file you download.

Comment: @Skynet who said anything about a database?

Comment: The OP talked about "Storing Images" so that does ring a Database bell!

Comment: You can use the libraries Picasso/Glide/UniversalImageLoader - the first two pretty much perform disk and memory caching without needing configuration, but I'm not sure about the third one since I've not used it that much.

Comment: i want to store images in internal memory how do i give dem different file names

Comment: i dnt understand your requirement, please explain where are you stuck ?

Comment: i cant save all images with different filenames